# rotate the screen or full-screen button on the YouTube player

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, youtube

I have applied to run the video from YouTube but there is a problem - when I put YouTube player code inside the button, the application does not function when I rotate the screen or go to full screen when I press the button of the YouTube player.

This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.watch);

    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.view2);
    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        final String VedioUrl = "fWuqQkdlC58";

        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VedioUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    Button PLAY = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    PLAY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            youTubePlayerView.initialize("AIzaSyB9U058ScB8F9zuBA-yuDlvOCAvLahxqeQ", onInitializedListener);
        }
    });
}
```

This image shows the problem when I go to full screen:

[image: Click here to see image]